# Extending unit test in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, testing, visual-studio-2017

I experiencing an issue with switching to Visual Studio 2017.
Following the guide in 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vstsqualitytools/2009/09/04/extending-the-visual-studio-unit-test-type-part-1/ we introduced a custom test derived from TestClassExtensionAttribute.
As described at the end of the guide, the new Attribute has to be registered in registry in

> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\
>   **10**.0_Config\EnterpriseTools\QualityTools\TestTypes\
>   {13cdc9d9-ddb5-4fa4-a97d-d965ccfc6d4b\TestTypeExtensions\DemoTestClassAttribute]

The issue is now, that Visual Studio 2017 has not the "classic" elements in the registry. 
What do I have to do, to make the custom unit tests run again?